# Как называются одинаковые по виду слова?

Tags: омографы

Объясните разницу в значении данных слов. Чем они различаются? Как называются такие слова: з**а**мок — зам**о**к, **у**же — уж**е**, выкуп**а**ть — в**ы**купать, засып**а**ть — зас**ы**пать, мук**а** — м**у**ка, кр**у**жки — кружк**и**?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 4):

Все слова, указанные в Вашем вопросе - **омографы.**

***Омографы*** в русском языке  (от греч. homos одинаковый + graphо пишу) — **слова одинакового написания, но различного** ***произношения***.
 В устной речи с ними всё ясно — говорящий при произношении слова интонацию делает на том слоге, ***на который падает ударение***.
Этот разряд слов способен ввести в заблуждение читающего.  В письменной речи часто ставят знак ударения, чтобы помочь читателю не ошибиться. Место ударения зависит от смыслового значения слова и определяется по контексту. ***В омографах без контекста нельзя определить, на какой слог ставить ударение.***

за́мок — замо́к,  у́же — уже́,  му́ка — мука́,  кру́жки — кружки́,  вЫкупать — выкупАть, засЫпать — засыпАть.

**Разница в значении слов появляется после постановки ударения**, например:

**За́мок (строение)** — здание (или комплекс зданий), сочетающее в себе жилые и оборонительно-фортификационные задачи. В наиболее распространённом значении — укреплённое жилище феодала в средневековой Европе.
**Замо́к** — механическое, электронное или комбинированное устройство фиксации. Применяется для запирания дверей, крышек, ёмкостей и пр., а также для обеспечения блокировки предметов с целью предотвращения их похищения и/или ограничения доступа.

**Дополнение**
Эту разницу отчётливо видно в словосочетаниях:

мук**А** для выпечки - м**У**ка совести;
в**Ы**купать ребёнка - выкуп**А**ть лекарство;
кр**У**жки для чая - кружк**И** пр интересам.